# Consulta SQL agrupando por faixa etária

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

Olá, preciso de uma forma de fazer uma consulta sql que me traga a quantidade de pessoas do sexo masculino e feminino. OBS: Tenho duas tabelas onde a primeira é cadastro nela tenho a coluna sexo e outra tabela que seria faixaetaria apenas com o nomedafaixaetaria. A tabela cadastro possui uma coluna chamada fok_faixaetaria que é uma chave estrangeira para a coluna faixaetaria. Gostaria de realizar uma consulta que trouxesse quantidade de pessoas do sexo masculino e feminino por faixaetaria.

```
SELECT COUNT(case when sexo= 'Masculino' then 1 end) AS Masculino,
COUNT(case when sexo= 'Feminino' then 1 end) AS Feminino FROM cadastro
where dataInicial = '01/08/2015' and dataFinal = '31/08/2015'
```

Como posso fazer a consulta sendo que tenho 6 faixa etarias e gostaria de contabilizar cada masculino e feminino por faixa etaria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deverá relacionar a tabela de cadastro com a tabela de faixa etaria e agrupar os resultados através da coluna de faixa etaria.

Utilize o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(case when sexo= 'Masculino' then 1 end) AS Masculino,
      COUNT(case when sexo= 'Feminino' then 1 end) AS Feminino, 
      FE.FAIXAETARIA AS [Faixa Etaria]
FROM 
      cadastro c (nolock)
      LEFT JOIN FAIXAETARIA FE (NOLOCK) ON FE.FAIXAETARIA = C.FOK_FAIXAETARIA
WHERE 
      dataInicial = '01/08/2015' and dataFinal = '31/08/2015' 
GROUP BY
      FE.FAIXAETARIA
ORDER BY
      FE.FAIXAETARIA DESC
```

Comment: Obrigado Resolvido!
Solução bem simples valeu!

Comment: se você tiver o habito de colocar `(NOLOCK)` em todas as suas consultas, espero nunca ter que fazer manutenção em um sistema feito por você... rework na certa.

Comment: @coreid, poderia marcar como resposta?

Comment: @TobyMosque, só utilizo em tabelas que tem muita concorrência, depende de alguns fatores.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates, neste caso você pode usar [Read Committed Snapshot Isolation](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation), apesar dos problemas, é melhor do que ler dados sujos

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates se quisesse colocar um order by nessa consulta como poderia fazer? Agora tenho a seguinte situação: a tabela cadastro está relacionada com a tabela faixaetaria:

Comment: @coreid, adicionei uma ordenação decrescente na consulta. Essa situação não é a mesma da query? Caso tenha outra dúvida, acredito que seja necessário abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates vou abrir outra pergunta, vou precisar de sua ajuda lá só um instante.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83997/order-by-sql-server-em-procedure