# Order by SQL Server em Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, procedure, order-by

Olá,
Estou com a seguinte situação:
 
Preciso selecionar a quantidade de atendimento de pessoas de algumas faixas etárias e dessas quantos são masculinos e femininos.
Tenho a seguintes tabelas:
`cadastro (id, natendimento, data, sexo, fokfaixaetaria)` e
 `faixaetaria (id, nomefaixaetaria)`
 a tabela cadastro possui a coluna faixaetaria que é chave estrangeira de faixaetaria. Atualmente estou com a seguinte consulta:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECIONAR_NUMERO_ATENDIMENTOS] 
@DATAINICIO DATETIME,
@DATAFIM DATETIME
AS

SELECT

faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria AS FaixaEtaria,
COUNT(case when sexo = 'Masculino' then 1 end) AS Masculino,
COUNT(case when sexo = 'Feminino' then 1 end) AS Feminino,
COUNT(fokfaixaetaria) AS Total

from cadastro 
left join faixaetaria on faixaetaria.id = cadastro.fokfaixaetaria

WHERE data_dte_cadastro BETWEEN @DATAINICIO AND @DATAFIM 
GROUP BY
faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria
```

Porém durante a consulta ela não vem organizada de acordo com a faixa etária,ou seja, queria que viesse 0 a 3 - tantos masculinos tantos femininos e total,
4 a 6 - tantos masculinos tantos femininos e total,
7 a 12 - tantos masculinos tantos femininos e total,
tudo na sequência. Isso não acontece ele agrupa de acordo com o que vem primeiro da minha tabela cadastro. Acredito que ai deva ter um order by só que não estou conseguindo colocá-lo.

Tabela faixaetaria:

[image: Tabela Faixa Etaria na Ordem]

Execução da Query:

[image: Execução da query acima]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: consegue enviar uma imagem de como a consulta está retornando?

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates a primeira imagem é da tabela faixaetaria a segunda é o resultado da consulta eu apenas gostaria que ficasse em ordem mas não na ordem de como elas são cadastradas na tabela cadastro e sim por uma questão de estética ficar em ordem igual como está na tabela faixaetaria, isso facilita em um relatório que irei fazer, só que não consigo colocar o order by no sql dá erro após o group by: `O nome de coluna "faixaetaria.id" é inválido na cláusula ORDER BY porque não está contido em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisas de criar uma subquery. O SQL Server permite incluir no GROUP BY colunas que não aparecem na instrução SELECT. Basta adicionar a coluna id no GROUP BY e fazer a ordenação usando a nova coluna incluida no GROUP BY.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECIONAR_NUMERO_ATENDIMENTOS] 
@DATAINICIO DATETIME,
@DATAFIM DATETIME
AS

SELECT faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria AS FaixaEtaria,
       COUNT(case when sexo = 'Masculino' then 1 end) AS Masculino,
       COUNT(case when sexo = 'Feminino' then 1 end) AS Feminino,
       COUNT(fokfaixaetaria) AS Total

FROM cadastro 
LEFT JOIN faixaetaria 
  ON faixaetaria.id = cadastro.fokfaixaetaria

WHERE data_dte_cadastro BETWEEN @DATAINICIO AND @DATAFIM 
GROUP BY faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria, faixaetaria.id
ORDER BY faixaetaria.id
```

Em resposta ao comentário, sim é possível. Basta, por exemplo fazer

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECIONAR_NUMERO_ATENDIMENTOS] 
@DATAINICIO DATETIME,
@DATAFIM DATETIME
AS

SELECT faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria AS FaixaEtaria,
       COUNT(case when sexo = 'Masculino' then 1 end) AS Masculino,
       COUNT(case when sexo = 'Feminino' then 1 end) AS Feminino,
       COUNT(fokfaixaetaria) AS Total

FROM faixaetaria 
lEFT JOIN cadastro 
  ON cadastro.fokfaixaetaria = faixaetaria.id
 AND data_dte_cadastro BETWEEN @DATAINICIO AND @DATAFIM 
GROUP BY faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria, faixaetaria.id
ORDER BY faixaetaria.id
```

Para incluir no conjunto de resultados um registo com o total podes usar o ROLLUP/GROUPING SETS fazendo o seguinte

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECIONAR_NUMERO_ATENDIMENTOS] 
@DATAINICIO DATETIME,
@DATAFIM DATETIME
AS

SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria) = 1 THEN 'Total geral' ELSE faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria END AS FaixaEtaria,
       COUNT(case when sexo = 'Masculino' then 1 end) AS Masculino,
       COUNT(case when sexo = 'Feminino' then 1 end) AS Feminino,
       COUNT(fokfaixaetaria) AS Total

FROM faixaetaria 
LEFT JOIN cadastro 
  ON cadastro.fokfaixaetaria = faixaetaria.id
 AND data_dte_cadastro BETWEEN @DATAINICIO AND @DATAFIM 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((faixaetaria.nomefaixaetaria, faixaetaria.id),())
ORDER BY ISNULL(faixaetaria.id, 99)
```

Comment: sua solução é bem simples!

Comment: Seria possível na consulta acima, trazer todas as faixas etarias da tabela faixaetaria mesmo que não tenham informações na tabela cadastro? e setar 0 para ambos os sexos e total?

Comment: Não deu certo ele somente trás os valores que estão na tabela cadastro.

Comment: Tem a certeza? Repara que na minha segunda query, estou a seleccionar todos os registos da tabela faixaetaria. A primeira e a segunda query têm uma base diferente: na segunda estou a seleccionar tudo da tabela faixaetaria, independentemente se está na tabela cadastro ou não.

Comment: Repara também que já não existe cláusula Where. Isto é importante para não excluir registos da tabela faixaetaria que não existem na tabela cadastro.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo! Não tinha percebido a não existência da cláusula Where.

Comment: Mas uma dúvida, se eu quisesse somar os valores da tabela total e exibir em uma única coluna apenas a soma de todos os valores da tabela total como posso fazer? Estou fazendo da seguinte forma mas não está dando certo ele repete e trás valores errados: `SUM(fokfaixaetaria) AS TotalGeral` Dento da consulta acima conforme você me passou.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27724/discussion-between-bruno-and-coreid).